Moving row of completed task to specific "completed" google sheet when using multiple sheets
I'm a construction worker trying to create an apps scripts for our work task list in google sheets.  My code is below (this code worked when there were just 2 sheets (task list & completed task list). Once I added multiple job task sheets (along with multiple "completed" task sheet, the code doesn't work anymore.  I've tried adding sheet names, but it still didn't work, so I rolled it back to this initial script that did work (for 2 sheets only).
sample spreadsheet
function onEdit(e){
  if (!e) throw "Do not run from Editor. This function runs automatically whenever an edit is made."

  moveToCompleted(e);
}

function moveToCompleted(e){
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() != "CochranTaskList","CartisanoTaskList" || r.columnStart != 1 || r.rowStart < 4) return;
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("CompletedCochranTasks","CompletedCartisanoTasks");
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,3).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow() +1, 1,1,3));
  src.deleteRows(r.rowStart);
}


Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. You may find it easier to use a Group by view instead of using a script to move rows from one tab to another. See Sort & filter your data and Use tables in Google Sheets.

Thanks, this worked, I just needed to add each sheet name as both the index and destination sheet names.  thank you

I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See What should I do when someone answers my question?

Use Array.indexOf(), like this:
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) throw new Error('Do not run from Editor. This function runs automatically whenever an edit is made.');
  moveToCompleted_(e);
}

function moveToCompleted_(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart !== 1 || e.range.rowStart < 4) return;
  const index = ['CochranTaskList', 'CartisanoTaskList'].indexOf(sheet.getName());
  if (index === -1) return;
  const destSheetName = ['CompletedCochranTasks', 'CompletedCartisanoTasks'][index];
  const dest = e.source.getSheetByName(destSheetName);
  sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 3).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
  sheet.deleteRows(e.range.rowStart);
}

See Array.indexOf() and Array.
